# High performance distributed asynchronous RPC in java

Tags: java, asynchronous, communication, rpc, distributed

I would like to do RPC to a list of clients with the following requirements:

- the server does not know the clients (implies a kind of broker?) and the cleints do not know the server
- there may be several clients - they share the load to treat the RPC
- The RPC is asynchronous
- very fast (round-trip < 1ms)
- optional : offers a fail-over mechanism.

It can be done with underlying tools which are not really intended for that (Hazelcast is an example).

What would you use for such requirements?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would use ActiveMQ as it's easy to get started with and unit test.

It can support 20K messages per second which are likely to be enough.

If you need faster than this, consider using HornetQ, but you would need to test it is suitable for your high performance needs.

It is possible to switch one JMS provider for another pretty easily.

---

If you need really high performance you could consider a library I wrote, Java Chronicle.  It's not designed for load balancing but can support over one million messages per second from a single producer.

Comment: I am not convinced by JMS solutions as I don't need to store messages and all. It seems too much overhead for me. I also need a round trip < 1ms

Comment: I am actually thinking of doing something over zeromq

Comment: 1000 micro-seconds is a pretty long time.  Most JMS solutions should support this.  Java Chronicle supports latencies around 100 micro-seconds over TCP (round trip).

Comment: ZeroMQ is a good choice as well.  It is fairly low latency over a network. (Over loop back it is surprising slow 35 micro-seconds compared with 10 micro-seconds for plain TCP)

Comment: Your lib seems interesting, I would still need to build the RPC stuff on top of it I guess.

Comment: Have a look at the demo sub-module but yes you would need some RPC on top no matter which way you go.

Answer (score 0):

see this asynchronous frameworks:https://github.com/reactor/reactor
and the slides:http://www.slideshare.net/eonnen/high-performance-network-programming-on-the-jvm-oscon-2012.